# Laravel mix generates relative paths

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

On production, to load my assets I use for example:

```
<link href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and expect to see when compiled:

```
<link href="https://example.com/css/app.083fd04ba374238b03b23e742c997718.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

However I am just seeing the relative path:

```
<link href="/css/app.083fd04ba374238b03b23e742c997718.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**webpack.mix.js:**

```
mix
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/print.scss', 'public/css')
  .copy([
    'node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap',
    'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts',
  ], 'public/fonts')
  .sourceMaps();

if (mix.config.inProduction) {
  mix
    .version()
    .disableNotifications();
} else {
    //
}
```

On latest version of Laravel (5.4.21). Using nginx, forcing https on Ubuntu 16.04. No idea why the paths are not full, but relative.

**EDIT:** I am also seeing the same behavior locally if I try to use `mix` vs `asset`, without `https`. Protocol seems not matter here actually.

Comment: You should select @Devon answer - it's the correct answer and much simpler one.

Comment: `/css/app` is an absolute path, not a relative one…

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to use the [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset) helper to prepend your APP_URL.

```
<script src="{{ asset(mix('css/app.css')) }}"></script>
```

Comment: Works prefectly, no need of custom helper. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you check out the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L558), that is how it is designed to work. You could always write your own helper.

You need to add this to a [helpers](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1) file.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;

if (! function_exists('mixUrl')) {
    /**
     * Get the path to a versioned Mix file.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  string  $manifestDirectory
     * @param  string  $baseUrl
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    function mixUrl($path, $manifestDirectory = '', $baseUrl = null)
    {
        static $manifest;

        if (! starts_with($path, '/')) {
            $path = "/{$path}";
        }

        if ($manifestDirectory && ! starts_with($manifestDirectory, '/')) {
            $manifestDirectory = "/{$manifestDirectory}";
        }

        if (file_exists(public_path($manifestDirectory.'/hot'))) {
            return new HtmlString("//localhost:8080{$path}");
        }

        if (! $manifest) {
            if (! file_exists($manifestPath = public_path($manifestDirectory.'/mix-manifest.json'))) {
                throw new Exception('The Mix manifest does not exist.');
            }

            $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents($manifestPath), true);
        }

        if (!is_null($baseUrl)){
            if (strlen($baseUrl) > 1 && Str::endsWith($baseUrl, '/')) {
                $baseUrl = substr($baseUrl, 0, -1);
            }
            return new HtmlString($baseUrl . $manifestDirectory . $manifest[$path]);
        }

        if (! array_key_exists($path, $manifest)) {
            throw new Exception(
                "Unable to locate Mix file: {$path}. Please check your ".
                'webpack.mix.js output paths and try again.'
            );
        }

        return new HtmlString($manifestDirectory.$manifest[$path]);
    }
}
```

called from blade like

```
<script src="{{ mixUrl('/css/app.css', '', 'http://example.com') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is exactly what I was going to end up doing anyway. Seems kind of odd that this is the functionality but either way I got it working.

Comment: Glad it helped! After working with Laravel for a while, once it doesn't make sense I head to the source.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use `asset()` helper. But there is another way to handle this by using `url()` or `secure_url()` helper

```
<script src="{{ url(mix('css/app.css')) }}"></script>
```

**or**

```
<script src="{{ secure_url(mix('css/app.css')) }}"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my function called from a TwigExtension, on laravel 5.* you can do a helper function.

```
// use Illuminate\Foundation\Mix;

function mix_url($path, $manifestDirectory = ''){

    return asset(app(Mix::class)(...func_get_args()));
}
```

Also you need to define the ASSET_URL on your .env